# conditional expected value of mean preserving spread

Tags: probability

My first post on here, and my math skills are more than a little rusty. I have a simple question for you: assume $Y$ is a mean preserving spread of $X$.

I'm trying to find a general proof for the following: $$E(X | X > Y) < E(Y | Y > X)$$

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information about typesetting your question so it is easier to read.  Also, you should give some indication of what you have tried before expecting much help.

Comment: I'd add more if I add an interesting sketch of proof. Both results, particularly the first, seem very intuitive, and you can generate plenty of examples that behave that way. But so far, I couldn't find a way to get a general proof.

Comment: Please delete the duplicate question from mathoverflow, since you now asked it here.

Comment: Done. No luck so far, and the deadline is approaching (this proof is instrumental for one of the applied results in my Master's thesis) -  any help would be greatly appreciated.